# Why would a warrior tribe be dependant on a pacifist tribe?

Tags: warfare, civilization

I have two small tribes which are in a similar, small geographical location. One of the civilisations is a group of warriors, called Wolves, who have trained to be warriors since children. The others, which is more numerous is called Sheep, and they are pacifist, so do not fight. The Wolves are responsible for maintaining order in the city. For reasons, the Wolves are not allowed to speak to the Sheep, and they mostly live outside the walls of the city, only coming in to deal with the occasional criminal. Both groups are rather small - I'm thinking that the Sheep are somewhere around 5000-6000 and the Wolves would be around 500 in terms of population.

The problem, is that the Wolves are extremely good at fighting, so why would they not take over the Sheep? (they live in the mountains and it's quite an uncomfortable life, but they do get some food deliveries by the Sheep - of course since they can't communicate the food is sometimes not enough)

I have thought about a few ideas:

1. It is illegal. There was a treaty made like 200 yrs ago and so they stick to that. But because its been a long time, some people have forgotten, and new thinkers from the group are beginning to wonder why they should stick to the treaty. (This tension is important narratively, but I need more reasons for the other side than just it is illegal)
2. They can't farm for food. However, if they just take over, they can force people to farm for them, or since they are skilled fighters, they can hunt?

I would really appreciate any more suggestions that are a bit better. Oh- and one thing to note is that its sort of Medieval-ish technology with no magic, so please no magical solutions. Also the treaty thing includes religion.

Comment: Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. We're lenient with new users, but for future reference: (a) We do not allow questions about stories or character/group choices. This falls too much into that domain. (b) The [help/dont-ask] prohibits questions that suggest their own answers and then ask for more. We accept them if you explain why your answers *fail your problem,* such that they become limitations. (c) Per the [help/on-topic], brainstorming is discouraged. It is permitted if you can explain how you will judge a best answer.

Comment: let me guess: one tribe suffers scurvy and the other Kwashiorkor (not enough protein)...

Comment: "House greyjoy does not sow". Maybe its a simple division of labor and some sort of warriors code. The wolves see their job as to protect the sheep, and its part of their deep beliefs that taking away the sheeps freedom would be disonhorable precisely because the sheep do not fight. The wolves "do not sow", they have neither the skills nor inclination to produce, they fight, and they fight for their brothers the sheep, who provide them with all they require.

Comment: "For reasons, the Wolves are not allowed to speak to the Sheep" - how do they "maintain order" without communication?

Comment: You might want to review how the Comanches would raid Mexican farms and villages. And how the Pueblo people in New Mexico built towns to respond to the raids. Generally speaking, people being raided can bunch up into groups larger than the raiding parties. Depending on the distance, it can be hard to bring enough food and forage to raid a long distance with many people. Thus, the situation can "organically" last for hundreds of years. Comanches raided till repeater rifles brought a new technology to fight back with.

Comment: @JBH Thanks for the information - I will keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: There's a Pink Floyd song that's pretty close to your scenario: [Sheep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3GE-sfEbJ7I)

Comment: @Chieron I've been wondering the same thing, as my first idea before seeing the "no speak" rule was to suggest marital ties. Then my second thought to circumvent this issue was to say "OK, they can't speak, but it doesn't mean they can't communicate" (by writing, sign language, or whatever). But then I realized that I can't suggest something seriously without knowing what the person who asked the question has exactly in mind.

Comment: I was thinking that order is maintained because some wolves are looking into the city, in case anything bad happens, and if needed sheep usually start some smoke signal they send up to alert the wolves (in case anyone was being violent or commiting any serious crimes)

Comment: *"Feed us drinks! Get us laid!"*

Comment: Could you start by explaining how 'a similar, small geographical location' differs from 'the same location'?

Comment: Could you either explain, or drop the idea that for reasons purely your own, the Wolves are not allowed to speak to the Sheep?

Comment: As Chieron suggested, how could your Wolves maintain order without speaking to your Sheep?

How could your Wolves warn or arrest a Sheep without speaking?

Comment: How could the actual - rather than the relative - size of your groups matter?

What do you think might be wrong with your Sheep/Wolf ratio of 10/1, until you try to find any society in history or geography where cops meet citizens in any such numbers? Oops!

I suggest the closest you'll get is from extremely repressive societies; most obviously China, Russia or the former East Germany.

Do you suggest even they had a Sheep/Wolf ratio of 10/1?

Comment: Isn't the real problem two-fold?

How could your Wolves being responsible for maintaining order not make them superior today, let alone in your primitive society?

Why and how do your Wolves get deliveries from your Sheep when they can't communicate?

Being unable to communicate, to me, necessarily means they can't discuss how much, or of what, or when anyone needs. How does that sit with you?

Comment: Who in your world would care more about a treaty made like 200 yrs ago than what their children had to eat today?

Since however important that tension is narratively, your Question is clearly asking us to do your work for you, what percentage are you prepared to pay for that help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Passive Resistance

The Sheep (though some heavily loaded names here) aren't weak, they're *pacifists*.  If this includes not putting up resistance to being conquered, they've clearly got incredibly strong personal and cultural mores as far as violence is concerned.

So if someone conquers them and demands that they do something... they don't.  If their conqueror threatens to kill them and their family if they don't do the thing... they still don't.  If their conqueror tortures them, sets fire to their home, beats them... they calmly take it and continue to refuse to do what is demanded of them.

What good is "owning" a farming community if they won't farm for you?  If, however, under the existing unspoken agreement, they get food from the community *gratis*, rocking the boat seems inadvisable.

### What about hunting?

The Sheep also cultivate a very specific plant that contains a large amount of a nutrient vital to your species' continued health.  Maybe the amount of food sent by the Sheep to the Wolves isn't always enough in terms of caloric content, but it always contains enough of the special plant that deficiency illnesses are kept at bay.

If the Sheep cannot be compelled to work, and the cultivation of this plant is complicated, "taking over" the Sheep would doom the Wolves, even if the Wolves could fully supplement their caloric intake with hunting.

Comment: I really liked the plant idea, because I was planning to use a specific plant for something completely unrelated, but I guess if they are the same plant it might make more sense.

Comment: I really like this idea. It also gives a nice hook for the "treaty" from the question. 200years ago the wolves tried exactly that. They took over and tried everything they could to force the sheep to cultivate that plant, almost resulting in mutal extinction. A new wolf leader was chosen and he offered the sheep the treaty.

Comment: The plant thing seems like a "trade secret" or "tribal knowledge" thing. You can generalize: Knowledge is harder to steal than land, and there is knowledge (or even better, difficult to learn expertise) the sheep have that the wolves need, but can't force.

Comment: Uhhh I want to read this book. Love pacifism as survival strategy

Answer (score 21):

Have you forgotten that in the past it was commonly accepted to have a society were someone worked for all, someone fought for all and someone else prayed for all?

Sure, the soldiers would have taken over the religious men in the blink of an eye, but they needed them to justify their own existence. And the religion needed a strong arm to enforce and support itself, when the praying fell short of providing concrete support.

You're just the nth iteration of this routine.

Comment: *Language and writing were also made available, the poetry of Khitai, the philosophy of Sung; and he also came to know the pleasures of women, when he was bred to the finest stock. But, always, there remained the discipline of steel.*

Answer (score 16):

### Frame Challenge:

A purely warrior culture i.e. one where the *only* duty of all members is to fight and nothing else?  No hunting/gathering or farming, no craftsmen, builders or metal workers, no storytellers/scribes or traders? Couldn't exist. They either have to have sub classes within their own culture who perform all non-military duties like for instance the Samurai or Spartans did or else they have slaves who do all vital, non-military tasks for them. It's that or starve to death.

And even if they have slaves? There have to be overseers amongst the warriors whose job is to give orders and keep everything running. Which by default  means those overseers *have* to be allowed to communicate with the slaves even if all the warriors do not.

This means you need options. Firstly and in the absence of 'Wolf' artisan and farmer sub classes etc you don't mention gender. So it's unclear if there are male and female warrior tribe members. If there are and only the males fight? There's one answer right there. The women talk/speak for the tribe.  If all members of the tribe regardless of gender are warriors? You need other solutions.

So perhaps old members of the Wolf tribe who have survived many years of combat are selected and appointed to be the tribes 'speakers to the Sheep'. Perhaps warriors born with a physical handicap or otherwise too badly injured to fight any longer are appointed. Finally perhaps the Wolf tribe 'adopt' a small number of carefully selected young (male) children every year from the Sheep tribe and indenture them as life long 'speakers' for the Wolf tribe. The speakers are not warriors but because they have been raised as Wolf tribe members from the day they could walk they are tolerated as second class members. However make sure to only ever adopt males and castrate them when you do. You don't want the riff raff breeding with 'real' warriors do you. :)

Comment: Frame challenge to the frame challenge: symbiosis. A warrior tribe can exist if there is another tribe who provides everything they need to keep living - food, weapons, etc. Maybe they are a pacifist tribe who live in the nearby city. That's what the question is about.

Comment: @DJClayworth The question clearly states that there is no communication between the two tribes. Zero!  The frame challenge relates to the inescapable need for some form of communication/intermediaries between the two tribes if the pacifists are to supply the warriors with all essential needs. A medieval society of any form could not exist without it. Even cloistered communities of monks who have taken vows of silence and cut themselves off from the outside world have rules/formal mechanisms for communication with that outside world when needs dictate.

Comment: This gets me thinking:  the Wolves hate to, or can't, do any administrative work at all.  Nothing but fighting.  A generation or two ago, the Wolves _DID_ conquer the Sheep--and within a couple of years, the Sheep were ruling the Wolves' tribe.  It was only with great difficulty that the Wolves finally got free, and they don't want to do that again.

Comment: Alternatively, the Wolves have conquered the Sheep in the past and forced them to feed them, and the food wasn't nearly as good as what the Sheep used to provide freely.

Comment: Framechallenge to the Framechallenge: SPARTA! The soldier-state did exist.

Comment: @Trish. Already mentioned in my answer and no the Spartans weren't an exclusively warrior based society. Firstly they had an underclass of serfs who were owed by the Spartan State called Helots who were responsible for all the farming & manual laboring tasks. A second class called the Perioeci formed a sort of middle class who acted as traders and craftsmen of the Spartan  State. They could fight if required to but were not full time soldiers. On top were the Spartiate who were full time soldiers and by law NOT allowed to do any of the tasks the Perioeci or Helots did.

Comment: No! Only fighting! ONLY! Walking to where the fighting is? NO! FIGHT NOW! Sleeping? NO! NEVER SLEEP! ONLY FIGHT!  Eating and drinking? NO! ONLY THE STILL-LIVING FLESH AND BLOOD OF YOUR ENEMIES. Expelling waste? NO! PEE YOUR PANTS AND FIGHT! Putting on pants?! NEVER MIND, WE'RE ALL FIGHTING NAKED ANYWAY.

Comment: @g s One presumes of course that it's still OK however to 'oil yourself up' before running into battle naked. And do a war dance first of course (with disco lights and the band slamming out a Bee Gees tune).

Answer (score 10):

## The warrior tribe are nomadic raiders.

Like many warrior cultures in history, the warrior tribes don't like settling down, rarely have permanent settlements, and highly value freedom.

They get most of their supplies via hunting and raiding, but their local area is heavily overhunted. The pacifists supply them with enough food as tribute to maintain them, and in return the warriors drive off external enemies who would destroy or enslave the pacifists.

The mountain is a much more defensible base and the warriors are very comfortable living there. No external enemy can hurt them. In times of great strife, the sheep have moved up with their supplies onto the mountain to survive.

## The sheep provide tribute

The sheep produce enormous supplies and their farming keeps them happy. They have trading networks to get rare supplies which the wolves love. The wolves have no incentive to destroy them, since they get enough tribute to survive as is.

Answer (score 8):

**They're *all* pacifists. The warriors have a special dispensation from God to righteously kill (certain) people and take their stuff (under certain circumstances).**

This is backed up by the indirect threat of violence: if you don't do what (the church says) God says, you're officially the sort of people that your neighbors are allowed to righteously kill and expropriate. However, most people, including most of the warriors, *really believe* in the pacifism, so the threat isn't really an exercise in compulsion, it's more of a reassurance that bad actors will be stopped.

Your scenario then becomes pretty close to how things worked out in real life medieval Europe, just simplified and idealized.

---

As an aside - you'll want to either do some serious research into real medieval communities or introduce a little bit of magic or a whole lot of luck to give you enough wiggle room to make up your own social dynamics without running out of realistic food production.

Answer (score 7):

some options:

**Kids**. A fanatical warrior culture would have no means of raising children. Not only their culture would have no time, skill and inclination to raise children, but consider that women raised in a brutal bootcamp-like environment in which they train alongside men to be hardcore engines of death, are very likely to become infertile. This can even be emphasized by the Warrior women removing their breasts (maybe even personally, without anesthetic, to accentuate their hardcoreness!), taking herbs and mushrooms that increase their testosterone, and train day and night like Olympic athletes.

This would make the Spearwives/Shieldmaidens/She-Wolves nearly completely infertile, and the Wolf Tribe dependent on adopting preteens from the Sheep (possibly some bloody and physically demanding trial would be required).

Answer (score 6):

**The Hunger-ish games**

Every Year, 10 members of each tribe are expelled from the tribe into the wilderness.

Each group of 10 is different - but the end result is usually one of 3 outcomes:

- The Wolves enslave the sheep, but everyone ends up dying because pissing off the people who forage your food is never a good long term strategy
- Everyone avoids each other and eventually dies.
- **When the Sheep and the Wolves mutually co-operate in order to both do what they are best at, everyone survives**

It serves as a constant reminder to **both** tribes that Domination might have a short-term gain, but it is never as successful as mutual co-operation.

Add in some ritual or religious over-tones, link it to a founding story for each tribe (think Darmok and Jalad, at Tenagra) for a historical context, give it another name - you mentioned you want religious tension in your story:

Have a faction starting to belief that this ritual has lost it's meaning, that the participants are just going through the motions and want to return to a more visceral time, conversely have another group that thinks this ritual is barbaric and a relic and not needed anymore because 'We hold these truths to be self-evident' - and each group is seeking to undermine the foundation of the society for their own reasons.

Comment: +1. Not only do you provide a plausible explanation but also the cultural background for this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

**Religion**

The wolves are raised to be tough and strong and the sheep are weak and soft. The wolves survive by hunting and the tribute paid to them from the sheep. If the hunting is bad then the weakest will die but leave the pack stronger for it.

The don't associate with the sheep as they don't want to be infected with their weakness. Soft beds create weak warriors.

Religion is always a good reason for illogical behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

**Money**

The wolves are well paid by the sheep for their efforts, and are happy with the arrangement. Amongst the sheep are economists, farmers, builders, workers, merchants, etc. i.e. people who know how to earn and manage money for the society.

Yes the odd wolf gets his own ideas that he could get more money by going into the city and raiding the sheep but since the wolf society as a whole knows this is a bad idea (killing the "golden goose"), this one himself becomes designated a criminal or an outcast.

This would be like the security guards of a big company trying to take over the company. It wouldn't make sense!

Answer (score 3):

#### Someone has to work.

Looks the wolves don't like to. Okay, but everyone needs products. So, someone has to work. "Taking over the sheeps", what would that mean? They are already life and death ruler of the sheeps. Killing them, why? Who will work after that?

No, the Sheeps are valuable *work force* for the Wolves. If someone - for example, a competitor Wolf tribe - would appear, then the Wolves would fight for them.

P.s. compare the situation to the medieval nobility and peasantry.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to explain. However you might need to abandon the idea of two tribes, but instead have two (very separate) subgroups within one tribe.

Start with the people of the city being not only strongly pacifist but anti-violence. Anyone who practices violence is anathema - not to be talked to and not to be allowed as part of society. However like many beliefs this is not shared by absolutely everybody. A significant minority believe that self-defence is necessary for the people who survive.

So we have a subclass of people who believe in violence and undertake to practice it in defence of the city. Because of the majority view these people are shunned - they live outside the city, and never enter it unless absolutely necessary. These are your "Wolves". They train for war, practice martial arts, know the surrounding terrain. They also hunt and patrol the surrounding area. However because a lot of people tacitly acknowledge that they are necessary (even though they would never admit it in polite society) the Wolves are supplied with what is necessary for their life and lifestyle. Weapons, food, and building materials are surreptitiously provided to them. In return the Wolves practice the actual defence of the city.

Because violence is abhorred, anyone found to have committed violence in the city is sentenced to exile. Exile usually means joining the Wolves. This way of adding to their numbers makes up for the fact that there are far more men that women in the wolves. Sometimes young children, born in the Wolf encampments, are brought into the city and are raised as Sheep. Sometimes a Wolf may win admittance to the city by repenting of their violent ways (though most are proud of the role they play, and find it more exciting and fulfilling than life in the city).

The Wolves don't take over the city because they believe in the city. Even if they don't agree with it's values, it's still home. They also believe in the importance of their role. This is just an extension of current scenarios where soldiers will go off to far distant lands in defence of the country they love.

Answer (score 1):

### Wolves are mercenaries

In history you don't really have any fully pacifist societies with medieval technology level. But let's say their religion forbids them to kill. The Sheep then would still have to find some way of defending themselves against nearby tribes/kingdoms whose religion has absolutely no problems with killing.

Historically, the way non-martial societies accomplished this, is mercenaries. They pay other tribes/kingdoms to be their army. One historical example would the the Carthaginians - they weren't pacifist but weren't a very martial society either (there were exceptions, most famously Hannibal Barca), they were mostly into trading. Carthaginian armies mainly consisted of mercenaries, including Numidians, who were fierce nomadic warriors. So your Sheep pay Wolves to defend them from any invaders, and to keep order in their city. The number of Wolves is small, but they are very capable warriors, and Sheep's city has high and strong walls and is in a very naturally defensible position.

So why don't the Wolves take over the Sheep's city instead of working for them? Simply, because they aren't advanced enough. Running a big city (and by medieval standards, six thousand is pretty big) is diffucult. It requires some education, knowledge of administration and urban management that Wolves simply don't have. Usually when armies of nomadic tribesmen successfully attacked more advanced cities, they would sack them rather than take over - that is, they would kill a whole lot of people, take anything that looks valuable, burn down a bunch of buildings just for fun, and then leave with the loot they've taken to go back to their tribal lands. Maybe Wolves have done that in the distant past, but at some point their chieftains have decided that taking regular payments and food deliveries from the Sheep is more profitable in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Economy.

Sheep are not substantially weaker, they are just reluctant to fight. If confronted in equal numbers with Wolves, the result is in no way pre-determined. Wolves may have higher chances because of better training but are usually lower in numbers.

Sheep have a lot to lose in a fight - family, friends, land , etc... and their culture reflects this. This is why they consider fighting a last and a bad option.

Wolves, on the other hand, have weak concept of property or long term plans. They live for the moment.

The Sheep consider Wolves a part of their society and supports them economically (outright feeding them half of the time) and benefit from having a first line of defence.

Answer (score 0):

The Muskogean tribal towns, which were either “white” (peaceful, civic) or “red” (warriors);were a historical example of this.  Their people often wore red and white clothing and face paint to show their roles, and red and white symbols marked buildings.  [Nancy Shoemaker, in a 1997 article,](https://peopleofonefire.com/how_indians_got_to_be_red.pdf) argued that the Natives of the area understood the treaty between themselves and Great Britain—in which the British called themselves “White” and the Natives “Red,” said they wanted peace, asked the Muskogeans to fight on their behalf if attacked, and presented gifts much as a white Muskogean chief would do for a red one—in terms of their own red/white traditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Real historical example**

A very real example of this was the Israelites and the Egyptians in history, where the Israelites were shepherds which was an occupation that the Egyptians refused to do. It was considered a deplorable profession, but they were happy to eat the meat the Israelites produced. The Israelites were not a fighting people and needed to learn, yet Egypt was the world superpower of the day.

However eventually they got too big and made the Egyptians nervous, so they enslaved them in order to reduce their power.And the rest is history (and historically recorded).

Answer (score 0):

## Weapons technology

A dedicated warrior tribe spends its time conquering, defending, or training.  They don't take the time to perfect metalworking as it's considered an effete art; craftsmanship is limited to sharpening heavy objects.

On their martial travels, they encounter the artisan culture, whose metallurgy, smithing, and other applicable skills are set to making beautiful and practical artifacts.  (They would of course fight if forced to, but they're not as good at it.)  First gobsmacked by the quality of their fine knives (as an example of a practical object with martial applications), they realize they can gain a substantial advantage over their opponents with this technology.  They quickly surround the city...to defend it against any other customers.  The artisans are happy for the arrangement, they can still sell non-weaponry items through their more widely traveled protectors, and benefit as well from spoils of war.

It can start out as different cultural focus (think Athens and Sparta) but as they are now collocated with the warrior tribe, members of either tribe whose personal lifestyle preferences are more compatible with the other can freely switch subcultures, leading to the highly specialized status of each.  This promotes closer collaboration and trust, so the warriors never have to develop the technology themselves.  They would of course hold each other in some friendly contempt (think doctors vs. soldiers, or lawyers vs. engineers).

Answer (score 0):

**Culture of honor**

The Wolves could see as dishonorable to attack groups they consider inferior relative to warfare or fighting, e.g. see the [Wikipedia article on chilvary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chivalry#Origins_in_military_ethos):

> Chivalric codes encompassed regulations such as pledging loyalty to
> the overlord and upholding warfare rules. These rules dictated
> refraining from attacking a defenseless opponent and prioritizing the
> capture of fellow nobles [...]

The advantage of this explanation, similar to your "illegal" idea, is that some members of the Wolves group could question this aspect of their culture (e.g. having a different interpretation of what honor means), making it possible to have conflicts between members of the group.

It may also give you more flexibility, as violating a cultural norm or code of honor may have different implications and more grey areas than violating a law or treaty.

Answer (score 0):

### Culture and tradition (can be mixed with religion)

They don't attack them because that's *how it's always been*.

Their culture is mainly based on discipline and respect, as well as effacement of the self in favor of the group. They have exteremely pervasive rites and customs that govern all aspects of life. Any individual that does not conform to them is ostracized, and if they do not rectify themselves, tied up and left in the wild for the beats to feast upon.

Now their ancestral texts involve some kind of commandment saying not to attack the Sheep. Or perhaps their code of honor / traditions involves some kind of chivalry-like values that forbids them from attacking the weak. Why is that in there?  nobody remembers, but they'll still do it, as nobody has questioned it and stayed alive.

So nobody does, or will, attack, because that's what tradition dictates.

Answer (score 0):

The wolves are raised in their early life by the sheep. Just like a son can soon overpower and dominate his mother in our society, it rarely happens that the son turns on the mother. Some genetic trait bred into the populations.

Answer (score 0):

### Alcohol

Lets use a real world example, what was one of the biggest advantages of cities and agriculture according the people that lived in them, alcohol! One of the big draws cities had to hill folk was abundant alcohol and bread.

**The sheep brew beer**, the wolves don't have the slightest clue how they do it but they like it. So they trade stuff they take from raids to the sheep for beer, ale, whatever. They also trade security services and could trade stuff from the mountains like ore, gems, or hunted meat. Much like real world warrior cultures they don't steal from their community of sheep but from other tribes sheep that is other cities and communities.

Also you don't need to speak to trade, A lot of trade can be accomplished with just showing goods and hand gestures.